# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'short_description' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel

I recieved error while i tried php artisan db:seed

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'short_description' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `categories`
> (`name`, `slug`, `short_description`, `description`, `regular_price`,
> `SKU`, `stock_status`, `quantity`, `image`, `category_id`,
> `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (atque dicta aut voluptatum,
> atque-dicta-aut-voluptatum, Id repellat nesciunt sit omnis et nihil
> magnam. Incidunt a voluptatum praesentium tempore non et nesciunt.
> Saepe iste qui voluptatem. Rerum nobis voluptatibus sint
> voluptatibus., Nulla modi quos porro numquam eius ullam sed. Ad
> voluptatibus quia velit. Voluptas iure molestiae veniam qui. Eos et
> qui quod nemo repudiandae fugit eos esse. Iste omnis ratione sunt non
> magni repudiandae distinctio. Est quia fugiat tenetur eum aspernatur
> distinctio. Rem excepturi magnam quaerat dolorem et adipisci tenetur.
> Temporibus quasi possimus sit exercitationem qui. Quia vel porro
> praesentium delectus reprehenderit enim similique. Quis quos et cum
> commodi nostrum., 330, DIGI378, instock, 158, digital_2, 2, 2021-04-16
> 21:12:05, 2021-04-16 21:12:05))

#### Category model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "categories";
}
```

#### Product model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "products";
}
```

#### Product schema (`2021_04_02_190519_create_products_table.php`)

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('short_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('reqular_price');
            $table->decimal('sales_price')->nullable();
            $table->string('SKU');
            $table->enum('stock_status',['instock','outofstock']);
            $table->boolean('featured')->default(false);
            $table->unsignedInteger('quantity')->default(10);
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->text('images')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullabe();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

#### Category schema (`2021_04_02_212544_create_categories_table.php`)

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

#### Product factory

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Category::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $product_name = $this->faker->unique()->words($nb=4,$asText=true);

        $slug = Str::slug($product_name);

        return [
            'name' => $product_name,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'short_description' => $this->faker->text(200),
            'description' => $this->faker->text(500),
            'regular_price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(10, 500),
            'SKU' => 'DIGI'.$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(100, 500),
            'stock_status' => 'instock',
            'quantity' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 200),
            'image' => 'digital_'.$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, 22),
            'category_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 5),
        ];
    }
}
```

#### Category factory

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Category::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $category_name = $this->faker->unique()->words($nb = 2, $asText = true);

        $slug = Str::slug($category_name);

        return [
            'name'=>$category_name,
            'slug'=>$slug,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You `categories` table has no column named `short_description`, it would be `priducts` table

Comment: Sir, you don't need to define `$table` if it already follows [Laravel's convention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names)... Also, please, read more about PSR as your code does not have spaces and a lot of simple stuff that makes it ugly and unreadable... Setup your IDE with good tools...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On **ProductFactory**, change :

```
protected $model = Category::class;
```

to,

```
protected $model = Product::class;
```

Comment: Please mark the asnwer as `accepted ✅`, if it helped

Comment: Thank You, That worked!